# SSH is slow to make a connection

Tags: ssh, connection, performance

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10, and whenever I try to SSH into my servers it's very slow. Before it displays the password prompt, it can take between 40 seconds and 60 seconds.

I use:

```
ssh myuser@myserver.com
```

Once I'm logged in, everything is fine and it works fast.

Why does it take so long, and how can i fix it?
Are there any options in the SSH command I can use?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is slow because the OpenSSH daemon uses DNS to run a reverse lookup on the client hostname to make sure it's valid

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

Comment out the following lines

```
#GSSAPIAuthentication yes
#GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

OR

add this:

```
UseDNS no
```

Comment: There is an sshd_config file for the server side and ssh_config for the client side. Setting these options on the client and the server in the ssh_config file didn't help me. Only after I set `GSSAPIAuthentication no` and `GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes` and added `UseDNS no` in the server's sshd_config file did it speed the connection up for me.

Comment: Is there no security implication of doing this?

Comment: @TheStoryCoder good question, ill have to double check, you triggered my curiosity now...

Comment: After added `UseDNS no`, I got `Bad configuration option: usedns` when I tried to ssh login another server.

Comment: I got locked out and had to use KVM when I tried metakermit's suggestion.

Comment: Try setting `UseDNS` to `no` in `/etc/sshd_config` or `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. NOT `/etc/ssh_config`!

Comment: Shoid I do it on remote or client machine?

Comment: @alper client machine

Answer (score 14):

This is just a complement of the answer of Book Of Zeus. In case you don't have root access (sudo), you can still configure it.

You need to edit your "user ssh_config" file which is:

```
vi $HOME/.ssh/config
```

(Note: you would have to create the directory $HOME/.ssh if it does not exist)

And add:

```
Host *
  GSSAPIAuthentication no
  GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
```

You can do so on a per host basis if required :) example:

```
Host linux-srv
  HostName 192.158.1.1
  GSSAPIAuthentication no
  GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
```

Make sure the IP address match your server IP. One cool advantage is that now ssh will provide autocomplete for this server. So you can type `ssh lin` + `Tab` and it should autocomplete to `ssh linux-srv`.

You can add a bunch of usefull options so that you don't have to type them each time:

```
User <a user>
Port <a port number>
IdentityFile <a specific private key>
Compression yes
....
```

So instead of typing `ssh -C -p 1022 -i ~/.hidden/prv-key-4096bit superuser@192.158.1.1` a simple `ssh linux-srv` would suffice!